# Center-Align Form in Windows Form Designer

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010

I've become accustomed to the WPF designer, I'm wondering if it's possible to align a form in the center of the designer, rather than top-left.

[image: Center?]

Comment: Yes, make the design window smaller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no.  The designer in VS 2010 does not allow the user to situate the form in any other configuration.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer to this question is "No", visual studio does not have this feature.  While there are not any good options what I can think of to address this is to take a look at [Sharp Develop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sd/), an alternative open source solution to Visual Studio and if that does not have this feature in it, you can submit a bug into their issue tracking system and hope someone picks it up.  Perhaps if you are feeling frisky enough you can even take on this IDE feature yourself and submit a patch.  Like I said, not a good option, but it's an option.

Answer (score -1):

Go the designer view, then go to the start position into the properties, and then set I to the center screen